# In how many ways we can arrange $n$ men and $m$ women in a circle such that between every $2$ men we can have at most $m -1$ women?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

First, this not a question from any academic resource, I thought about it and I'm just wondering if it can be solved.

The question :

In how many ways we can arrange $n$ men and $m$ women in a circle (when $n ≥ 3$ , $m ≥ 2$ and $ n > m$ ) such that between every $2$ men we can have at most $m -1$ women?

First, I thought to arrange the men in the circle which is $(n -1)!$ options.

Now, it looks that we need to choose between $0$ to $m-1$ women between $2$ men, so it looks like we need to apply PIE, but I don't know how to approach it, so I would like to have a direction of how to solve it.

Comment: So basically any way except all men together and all women together? By the way please define whether two arrangements differing only by a rotation are counted as different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of ways we can arrange $n$ men and $m$ women is $(n+m-1)!$.

Now, the complementary event of what we want is the $m$ women being between two men, that is, all women being together and all men being together.

Place the $m$ women, there are $m!$ ways to do so.

Then, there are $n!$ ways to place the men (note that we don't have to account for possible duplicates as in circular permutations).

Thus, the number of ways to arrange the men and women as desired is $(n+m-1)!-n!\space m!$.